# Facebook Like Button Plugin Posts to og.likes instead of url_like

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

Background: I have implemented a normal Facebook Like Button to my page using XFBML. This is the button.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

I left out the src because the page is dynamic and I bind the src using jquery while the page loads.

```
$(".fb-like").attr("data-href", document.URL);
```

I subscribed an event to the button to do some data processing.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function (response) {
        console.log("like: " + response);
        LikeUrl(response);
        console.log('like: ' + location.href);
    });
```

Problem: I have click the like button to like for example this url: http://www.google.com/. Normally when I execute the following FQL

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?access_token=access_token&q=SELECT url FROM url_like where user_id=me()
```

it will return

```
{
   "data": [
      {
        "url": "http://www.google.com/"
      }
    ]
}
```

instead it returns empty data

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

So I checked

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes
```

and it is found there.

This is my first question on stackoverflow. Please tell if the information is not sufficient.

thanks!

Comment: It's not instead of, that's intended behaviour as to the FQL you may want to check this bug. http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/407658155957868?browse=search_501417719bef48457904563

Comment: @ phwd, I wonder why it previously was working on updating the like record to user_like table but now it has changed to og.likes.

@NirajShah Shah, sorry if I sound confusing, previously when a user click the like button, the record will be stored into user_like table but now it is stored to og.likes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be related to the Like Button migration that was [recently announced](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/07/25/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/). You can read more about the [Like Page Migration on Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/migration/). I think it's basically FB seperating Pages from Likes on the Open Graph.